# VerifyError in android test-project build tools v17

Tags: android, testing, junit, dalvik

Since installing v17 of the android build tools I am getting a VerifyError in my test project.

**A short description of my project structure:**

All jar files exist in my main projects *libs* folder

The test-project is a project that resides inside my main project

All Instrumentation tests exist in the same package as my activities.

I have one jar that is only needed for the test projects in my *libs* folder in the test project

Has anyone seen this?  Its happening on all my projects since updating.  Running the test produces an InstrumentationException: java.lang.VerifyError

Comment: try cleaning your entire project and then rebuilding?

Comment: I am doing clean builds.  Sorry for not clarifying that in the post.

Comment: **UPDATE**
So it looks like we are able to get around this but so far the process of doing so requires the following steps:
*1.* _ant clean debug_ on the main project
*2.* adb install main project
*3.* _ant clean debug_ on the test project
*4.* adb install test project
*5.* ant test *6.* _ant clean debug_ on the main project again *7.* adb install main project *8.* ant test on test project *9.* ... *10.* Profit

Comment: And after you do this once, you still need to continue to get broken builds and have to continue cleaning like this?

Comment: If I rebuild the test project no.  If I modify the main project I will get the VerifyError and have to redo these steps.

Comment: do the API levels betweeen your test and main projects correspond.  This usually happens because of library code with older versions of the platform.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski The target set in project.properties for both projects is android-10 and the minSdkVersion is set to 8 in the main project

Comment: what do you mean by "The test-project is a project that resides inside my main project". is it just the folder set up?I'm really not sure why all your cleaning/building steps would help

Comment: @Xav my folder hierarchy is main-project/test/... for the test project.  Im really not sure either about the building and cleaning but it works and makes absolutely no sense to me

Comment: @Xav I think I figured out whats going on... The first 2 steps above are not necessary.  Whats happening is that ant clean debug on the test project is generating a debug binary for the main project but it is not the same as the binary generated by ant clean debug run on the main projects build.xml

Comment: how does your test project reference your main project?

Comment: tested.project.dir=../ in the ant.properties file

Comment: I was able to reproduce. I did a fix today that seemed to have many effect. can you go to tools.android.com/download and get the anttasks.jar from there and put it in SDK/tools/lib/ (where there should already be one) and test with it. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

x...@android.com made a temporary fix for an issue I reported: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27608.

You can try to see if the new anttasks.jar file can fix your problem.

It fixed mine. [NoClassDefFoundError when running Instrumentation test with ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847443/noclassdeffounderror-when-running-instrumentation-test-with-ant)

Comment: I can confirm that the replacement anttasks.jar fixed this issue with ant for me to. To help future readers find this answer: an additional symptom I was seeing with this bug is that the ant "debug" task in the test subproject would recreate the main applications APK and corrupt it - mine would go from being 800KB down to 8KB in size, I guess this was leaving out all my dependent jar classes.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I have a test project using the library of "robotium".
I'd had the same problem, and soleved by following steps,

1. "Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries", delete "Android Dependencies" in my test project.
2. "Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries", delete two robotium jar and click "Add JARs" to re-import robotium jar in my test project.
3. "Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export", check two checkbok of robotium jar (and othera you want exported.)
4. Clean my test project.

I think you also solve the problem, Good Luck!

more information

[How to fix the “NoClassDefFoundError” with ADT 17](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17)

[Dealing with dependencies in Android projects](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects)

Comment: Deleting "Android Dependencies" can have side effects, for example won't the custom annotations in the sdk be loaded anymore.

Comment: Exactly!
Now, you can test by following configurations.

test project

1. Not Export: Android x.x.x
2. Not Export: robotium
3. Not Export: robotium
4. Not Export: Android Dpendencies

product

1. Not Export: Android x.x.x
2. Not Export: android-support-v4.jar
3. Not Export: Android Dpendencies

Answer (score 1):

in my case, first, add robotium-solo-2.5 in properties->build path->Libraries,and then move robotium-solo-2.5.jar to the top in properties->build path->Order and export, finally i solve this funny problem easily...

Answer (score 0):

“Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export”, and check all the references you want exported.

Answer (score 0):

The way Android deals with dependencies has recently [changed](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects). If you are using eclipse, then just remove your jar imports and place them in a "libs"-folder in the project root, and everything will be imported automatically.