# Android unable to register external jars

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I am getting this weird RunTime error. The classes compile easy on eclipse but when I run a class referring an external jar, its crashes with "unfortunately the app has to close".

I know that I have to add the jars in the Java Build path. I have done that. It used to work perfectly earlier. Someone, I was doing a clean Android SDK installation again and since then it has failed to work. This is my Device API version is 15 (Android 4.0.3)

And, the error is some linkage error of not finding the class. It only happens when I refer an external jar, normal android app doesn't crashes.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior : Must be some bug with most recent SDK tools - I just updated to R17. See this other bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847443/noclassdeffounderror-when-running-instrumentation-test-with-ant

Comment: hope your jar is in lib folder and you are using that path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

Comment: Thanks! I think the short answer for users on Stackoverflow is: rename your lib folder to libs folder.