# NoClassDefFoundError when using objenesis on Android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, cloning

I'm developing an android app which use the `com.rits.cloning` and `org.objenesis.*` libs to deep clone object.
The purpose is to add same object to my tree structure class twice or more without worrying that the original object is referencing to the same object.
Since the regular `clone()` just shallow copy the object, I use the mentioned libs.

Before develop the android project, I created a java project to implement my tree and it worked fine using those libs.
Then I imported it to the android project (and also add `com.rits.cloning`, `org.objenesis.*` as external lib and then check both libs in the `Java Build Path > Order and Export`).
But when I run it, right at the line where I call `deepClone()`, this error showed up in the LogCat and the app is force closed:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.<init>(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:40)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at org.objenesis.strategy.StdInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(StdInstantiatorStrategy.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.getInstantiatorOf(ObjenesisBase.java:90)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.newInstance(Cloner.java:291)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:468)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.deepClone(Cloner.java:327)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.*.project_monitoring.project.WBS.add(WBS.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.*.project_monitoring.project.ProjectUtility.demoPlan(ProjectUtility.java:101)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.*.project_monitoring.ProjectSelection.onCreate(ProjectSelection.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I googled and have tried this separately:

- clean the project
- remove `com.rits.cloning` and `org.objenesis.*` from the build path and readd
- reorder those libs so that they on right below the Android Dependencies
- reorder those libs so that they on top of all libs

I don't think it's because of eclipse update because I updated it weeks before this happen.

Here's the source code:

```
package com.*.tree;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.rits.cloning.Cloner;

public class MyTree {
    Data o;
    MyTree parent;
    ArrayList<MyTree> child = new ArrayList<MyTree>();

    public void add(MyTree tree) {
        Cloner c = new Cloner();

        MyTree temp =   c.deepClone(tree); //this is where the app crashed
        temp.parent = this;
        child.add(temp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyTree tree1 = new MyTree();
        MyTree tree2 = new MyTree();

        tree1.add(tree2);
        tree1.add(tree2);
        tree1.add(tree2);
        //The result wanted here is tree1 has 3 different but identical child objects
        //NOT 3 child which refer to the same one object
    }
}

class Data {
    double value;
}
```

Question:

- Why do I got that error and how do I get rid of it?
- Is there any other way to implement my tree?

Pardon my english.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse when you add an external library in the Java Build Path dialog, don't forget to also switch to the Order and Export tab and tick that library's name in the list. This is needed so that the library is found at run-time, not only at compile time.

[NoClassDefFoundError when running Instrumentation test with ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847443/noclassdeffounderror-when-running-instrumentation-test-with-ant/9958669#9958669)

Comment: Thanks, I included the answer as well.